# Reorder rows into single column

Tags: google-sheets

I have rows of data in `AdminSheet` and want to insert those into Main Data Table but it needs to be in that one column and have the spaces to look good. I found a [script online](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zrNShZaDWato2vAEGCzqCvcViSZIVA_VTft_Z6KZo5E/edit?usp=sharing) that would re-order them into one column but it took out all the spaces and it didn't fit the format.

Comment: Some screenshots would probably be very helpful to illustrate what you are trying to show in the sample sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using join and split, and transpose like this:

`=transpose(split(join(rept(" ;",5),indirect("A1:A"&counta(A1:A))),";"))`

[image]